# Print command result while executing from script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run from a shell script a C++ program that print some outputs (using `std::cout`), and I would like to see them in the console **while the program is running**.

I tried some things like this :

```
RES=`./program`
RES=$(./program)
```

But all I can do is to only display the result at the end : `echo $RES`...

How to display the outputs in run-time in the console, AND in the variable `RES` ?

Comment: Try `man tee`, and `man tty`. Then you can split the output stream so it is reproduced to the actual terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TTY=$(tty);
SAVED_OUTPUT=$(echo "my dummy c++ program" | tee ${TTY});
echo ${SAVED_OUTPUT};
```

prints

```
my dummy c++ program
my dummy c++ program
```

First we save off the name of the current terminal (because `tty` doesn't work in a pipeline).

```
TTY=$(tty)
```

Then we "T" the output (a letter `T` looks like one stream in at the bottom, 2 out at the top, and comes from the same "plumbing" metaphor as "pipe"), which copies it to the filename given; in this case the "file" is really a special device representing our terminal.

```
echo "my dummy c++ program" | tee ${TTY}
```

Comment: FYI, using all-caps names for your own variables is bad form; per [the relevant POSIX standard's guidelines on environment variable naming](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system and the shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. Since setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, this applies even when not explicitly exporting content to the environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
RES=( $(./program) )
echo ${RES[@]}
```

you can try in this way

Comment: Content is still captured, not streamed live (as the OP is asking for). Also, if your program outputs `*`, your `echo` will have not that `*` but a list of files in the current directory -- surely not correct behavior. Similarly, if your program outputs newlines or tabs, they'll be emitted as spaces instead by this code.

Comment: can you paste your cpp output

Comment: An answer that only works for the OP's output isn't helpful to anyone but the OP. Part of the point of StackOverflow is to have a knowledgebase that's useful to everyone; that's why building robust answers (that work even in unexpected circumstances, such as when a program has wildcards or newlines) is important. Anyhow, for a command that generates outputs that will generate the bugs described, consider using the following in place of `./program` for test purposes: `printf '%s\n' '*' $'hello\t\tworld'; sleep 5; echo "post-streaming content"`

Comment: For a fully correct implementation, one would see the first content without the 5-second delay, and the other content would have its original formatting.

Comment: you can use this method , i don't know whether this is your result or not

Comment: res=$(sed -n 'p;' <<< $(printf '%s\n' '*' $'hello\t\tworld'; sleep 5; echo "post-streaming content")&;wait)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary file

```
./program | tee temp
RES=$(< temp)
rm temp
```

You can generate a temporary file with unique name by using `mktemp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 res=$(sed -n 'p;' <<< $(printf '%s\n' '*' $'hello\t\tworld'; sleep 5; echo "post-streaming content")&;wait)     
 echo $res
 #output
 *
 hello           world
 post-streaming content
```

Comment: That still doesn't print anything -- even the first two lines -- until after the 5-second delay is complete. And `&;` is invalid syntax in POSIX sh and most if not all released versions of bash (because `&` itself is a command separator) -- which one are you testing with?

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: ...but are you sure that's actually your running shell? I'm guessing that you're using zsh -- unlike bash, `&;` is valid there.

Comment: Try running `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`; if that doesn't print anything, then `echo "$ZSH_VERSION"`.

Comment: ...that also explains why the `*` is literal for you -- zsh doesn't follow POSIX rules on expansion behavior.

Comment: wait some minutes

Answer (score 0):

```
[sky@kvm35066 tmp]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
res=$(printf '%s\n' '*' $'hello\t\tworld'; sleep 5; echo "post-streaming content")
echo "$res"

[sky@kvm35066 tmp]$ bash test.sh 
4.1.2(1)-release
*
hello           world
post-streaming content
```

i think the result is correct, and it is what you want